# How do I change the hover (focus) color of admin bar from frontend?

Tags: wp-admin, admin-bar

I'm styling my adminbar from frontend, I followed some tutorials to do this. The only thing I didn't get it done it was change the default blue text hover color and gray background hover color of the admin bar from Wordpress to my custom color.

When I put a mouse cursor in some item from admin bar it continues showing the default blue and gray text and backgroun color.

This is my code in functions.php of my theme

```
add_action('wp_head', 'change_bar_color1');

function change_bar_color1() {

?>

<style>
#wpadminbar .ab-empty-item, 
#wpadminbar a.ab-item, 
#wpadminbar > #wp-toolbar span.ab-label, 
#wpadminbar > #wp-toolbar span.noticon {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#wpadminbar{
    background:#ff6000;
    border-top:2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000000;
    border-left:2px solid #ff6000;
    border-right:2px solid #ff6000
}
#wpadminbar .quicklinks ul li a:hover {background:#ffffff}
#wpadminbar .ab-top-menu > li.hover > .ab-item,
#wpadminbar .ab-top-menu > li.menupop.hover > .ab-item,
#wpadminbar .ab-top-menu > li:hover > .ab-item,
#wpadminbar .ab-top-menu > li >.ab-item:focus,
#wpadminbar-nojs .ab-top-menu > li.menupop:hover > .ab-item,
#wpadminbar.nojq .quicklinks .ab-top-menu > li > .ab-item:focus { 
    color:#fff;background:#ffa948
}
#wpadminbar .menupop .ab-sub-wrapper {
    background:#fc8805;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ff6000;
    border-left:2px solid #000000;
    border-right:2px solid #000000
}
#wpadminbar .ab-submenu .ab-item,
#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul li a,
#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop.hover ul li a,
#wpadminbar-nojs .quicklinks .menupop:hover ul li a {
    color:#000000
}
#wpadminbar .menupop .menupop > .ab-item:hover:before,
#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul li a:focus,
#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul li a:focus strong,
#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul li a:hover,
#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul li a:hover strong,
#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop.hover ul li a:focus,
#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop.hover ul li a:hover,
#wpadminbar .quicklinks li a:hover .blavatar,
#wpadminbar li .ab-item:focus:before,
#wpadminbar li a:focus .ab-icon:before,
#wpadminbar li.hover .ab-icon:before,
#wpadminbar li.hover .ab-item:after,
#wpadminbar li.hover .ab-item:before,
#wpadminbar li:hover #adminbarsearch:before,
#wpadminbar li:hover .ab-icon:before,
#wpadminbar li:hover .ab-item:after,
#wpadminbar li:hover .ab-item:before,
#wpadminbar.nojs .quicklinks .menupop:hover ul li a:focus,
#wpadminbar.nojs .quicklinks .menupop:hover ul li a:hover {
    color:#ff0000
}
#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul.ab-sub-secondary,
#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul.ab-sub-secondary .ab-submenu {
     background:#ffb45f
}

</style>
<?php

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch your hook to [`'admin_bar_menu'`] and make things `!important`.

---

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'change_bar_color1' );

function change_bar_color1() {

    ?>

    <style>
        #wpadminbar .ab-empty-item, #wpadminbar a.ab-item, #wpadminbar > #wp-toolbar span.ab-label, #wpadminbar > #wp-toolbar span.noticon {
            color: #FFFFFF !important;
        }

        #wpadminbar {
            background: #ff6000 !important;
            border-top: 2px solid #000000;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
            border-left: 2px solid #ff6000;
            border-right: 2px solid #ff6000
        }

        #wpadminbar .quicklinks ul li a:hover {
            background: #ffffff
        }

        #wpadminbar .ab-top-menu > li.hover > .ab-item, #wpadminbar .ab-top-menu > li.menupop.hover > .ab-item, #wpadminbar .ab-top-menu > li:hover > .ab-item, #wpadminbar .ab-top-menu > li > .ab-item:focus, #wpadminbar-nojs .ab-top-menu > li.menupop:hover > .ab-item, #wpadminbar.nojq .quicklinks .ab-top-menu > li > .ab-item:focus {
            color: #fff !important;
            background: #ffa948 !important;
        }

        #wpadminbar .menupop .ab-sub-wrapper {
            background: #fc8805;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6000;
            border-left: 2px solid #000000;
            border-right: 2px solid #000000
        }

        #wpadminbar .ab-submenu .ab-item, #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul li a, #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop.hover ul li a, #wpadminbar-nojs .quicklinks .menupop:hover ul li a {
            color: #000000 !important;
        }

        #wpadminbar .menupop .menupop > .ab-item:hover:before, #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul li a:focus, #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul li a:focus strong, #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul li a:hover, #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul li a:hover strong, #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop.hover ul li a:focus, #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop.hover ul li a:hover, #wpadminbar .quicklinks li a:hover .blavatar, #wpadminbar li .ab-item:focus:before, #wpadminbar li a:focus .ab-icon:before, #wpadminbar li.hover .ab-icon:before, #wpadminbar li.hover .ab-item:after, #wpadminbar li.hover .ab-item:before, #wpadminbar li:hover #adminbarsearch:before, #wpadminbar li:hover .ab-icon:before, #wpadminbar li:hover .ab-item:after, #wpadminbar li:hover .ab-item:before, #wpadminbar.nojs .quicklinks .menupop:hover ul li a:focus, #wpadminbar.nojs .quicklinks .menupop:hover ul li a:hover {
            color: #ff0000 !important;
        }

        #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul.ab-sub-secondary, #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul.ab-sub-secondary .ab-submenu {
            background: #ffb45f !important;
        }

    </style>

    <?php
}
```

Comment: Wow! It worked! What was it missing in my code? "Make things important?" When I put "wp_head" it was my goal, because I'd like to show for all users the admin bar on my main page... :)

Comment: You might be able to put in your footer and skip the `!important` tag. Generally `!important` overrides cascading styles but this is really an issue with order and priority -- CSS 101. There may be an admin-styles.css that is getting enqueue that if you replace with a cleaned up version without overrides you wouldn't need to use dirty tricks like that.